# Windows service cannot read file but application can

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have a Windows Service that needs to read a text file every 90 seconds or so and then do some actions. The problem is that I get 'Access Denied' errors when reading the file from a service, but I can read the file just fine from an app (using the exact same code). This is my first service so maybe I am missing something obvious? Here is the relevant code for the service (**Doesn`t work**)

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        this.eventLog1.WriteEntry("my app in OnStart.");
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ServiceWorkerThread));
    }
    private void ServiceWorkerThread(object state)
    {
        while (!this.stopping)
        {
            update_DB();
            Thread.Sleep(90000); 
        }
        this.stoppedEvent.Set();
    }
    protected void update_DB()
    {
        try
        { 
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\jkoegler\\Desktop\\text.xml");
            //do a bunch of other stuff
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.eventLog1.WriteEntry(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And here is what gets logged:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
'C:\Users\jkoegler\Desktop\text.xml' is denied.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32
rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options,
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare 
share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare
share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean  
detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize)
at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding)
at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllLines(String path, Encoding encoding)
```

Now what gets me is that I can have this **EXACT** same code block (update_DB()) in a button click event in a regular windows forms app and it works fine. I can run the app at basically the same time as the service and it works just fine. What gives? I gave all users full access to the file and the folder. Thanks in advance

Comment: What user account is the windows service running under? It will need the same access as you have while running the application.

Comment: Try going into the services menu (Administrative Tools -> Services) -> right click your service -> Properties and then "Log on" on the second tab. Specify your own user account there and see if that works.

Comment: Yep, its logon is set to "Local Service". Giving that permission cleared up the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows services run as a specified user. You can view or change which user it is running under using the Services control panel.

Run: **services.msc**
or 
Access via the **Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services**

By default, it is probably running under the *Local Service* account, and that account probably doesn't have permissions to the file you are trying to read, but *your* account does.